# What has an "aura" for the purpose of Detect [Alignment] spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, alignment

A buddy of mine said something about only certain types of creatures/characters (such as outsiders, alignment subtypes, and divine/profane classes) generate an "aura" for the purpose of **[Detect [Alignment]](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectEvil.htm)** spells, thus, most normal characters wouldn't show up on **Detect [Alignment]** at all.  Is this true?  There is an aura gauge for "creatures", and by definition "creature" should include every type of character.

> *PHB pg306* **creature:** A living or otherwise active being, not an object.  The terms "creature" and "character" are sometimes used interchangeably.

So, in the end, **Detect [Alignment]** spells should reveal a matching alignment aura on even a standard Human Fighter if their alignment matches the spell correct?

Edit: After reading and discussing these answers and after discussing the definition of a "creature" with my friend he is now under the impression that he was confusing it with 2e rulings.

Comment: Is there something about the spell description - with  all the "aura strength" stuff - that does not answer this? http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectEvil.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Category:Detect_Spell) [rules](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Detect_Evil) indicate that **everything that isn't true neutral has at least a "faint" aura matching with it's alignment** (though I'd argue that faint auras are not a big deal and not very noticeable unless many overlap) and that specific circumstances need to be met in order to show up more strongly on alignment-detection effects.

From what I gather, the rules for properly showing up are as follows:

- Any creature that does not meet the requirements below, but has high enough HD (minimum 11 HD for an aura stronger than faint).
- Outsiders have an aura that matches their alignment (min. 2 HD for aura stronger than faint).
- Undead have an aura that matches their alignment, except for good ones, because according to RAW undead cannot be good (min. 3 HD for aura stronger than faint).
- Clerics have an aura corresponding to the alignment of their deity (except for clerics of true neutral deities or godless clerics who do not take an alignment-based domain), min. class level 2 for aura stronger than faint.
- Anyone enchanted with magical effects that are clearly aligned in some way will radiate that spell effect's alignment (min. casterlevel 3 for aura stronger than faint).
- Anyone sufficiently covered in magical items that are aligned will seem to radiate that aligment (probably only the case with aligned full-plate armor, otherwise it should be easy to tell that the aura does not originate from the person themselves), min casterlevel 3 for aura stronger than faint.

It is also specifically mentioned that

> Animals, traps, poisons, and other potential perils are not evil/good/lawful/chaotic, and
>   as such this spell does not detect them.

which should mean that **all entities of animal intelligence or lower cannot be detected** (should be obvious considering that any alignment other than true neutral requires a certain level of intelligence to make sense), unless they specifically meet any of the criteria mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

**Detect [Alignment] will detect any creatures of a particular alignment.**

What your friend is likely confused about is the Aura Strength mechanic.  Creatures like Clerics and Demons have a stronger aligned aura will detect as if they are stronger than a normal aligned creature would.  Basically, creatures with a particular alignment that don't have any particular connection to that alignment have a weaker aura that creatures that have a stronger connection.  For example, an evil level 11 Human Rogue would have a Moderate aura of evil, while a 2 HD [Dretch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/demon.htm) would have the same aura strength.

This is all spelled out in the spell description, along with a table that maps each type of creature to the various requirements for each aura strength category.